# At the Point of a Spear

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> My first prefix is relaxing
>
> My second prefix holds up mobile cloth
>
> My first infix is about average
>
> My second infix is only a piece
>
> My third infix makes you laugh and cry and stare
>
> My suffix is the first among two dozen or so
>
> I'm only six letters long
>
> And I'm frankly a proper noun
>
> What am I?

<sub>Bonus: How many spear points do you think there are?</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you are

> Sparta

My first prefix is relaxing

> Spa  -- you go to a spa to relax

My second prefix holds up mobile cloth

> As @WeatherVane pointed out: Spar (holds up a sail)

My first infix is about average

> par -- par is average

My second infix is only a piece

> part  -- part is a piece

My third infix makes you laugh and cry and stare

> art -- art evokes emotions and you look at it

My suffix is the first among two dozen or so

> a  -- first letter of 26 (the or so part of two dozen)

And I guess for the bonus, it is

> 300  -- the 300 Spartans who King Leonidas led into battle against over 300,000 Persian soldiers lead by "God-King" Xerxes

Comment: Second prefix: note that rot13(N fcne ubyqf hc n fnvy).

Comment: Very nice answer! Would you mind adding a few explanations in?